# Virtual Directory root vs Default web site root

Tags: asp.net, virtual-directory, iis-5

I am using iis 5.1 in which we have only only one default website,

I have two projects v2 and v3

my website points to v2 projects and have some folders images, styles etc
now i have a virtual directory under this website that is hosting project v3 and having the same folder hierarchy as v2

in the home page of the both projects i have

> img src="\images\edlogo.gif" alt="logo"/>

but this shows the same image that is in the v2 directory, How can i show different images for both projects.
using "\" get the root of the web site but how can i get the root of virtual directory under that website

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This static method returns you full http path to root folder of your application (web site or virtual directory)

```
public static string GetAppRootUrl(bool endSlash) { 
   string host = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority);
   string appRootUrl = HttpContext.Current.Request.ApplicationPath;
   if (!appRootUrl.EndsWith("/")) //a virtual
   {
       appRootUrl += "/";
   }
   if (!endSlash)
   {
       appRootUrl = appRootUrl.Substring(0, appRootUrl.Length - 1);
   }
   return host + appRootUrl;
}
```

So, you can write in your page:

```
<img src="<%= Server.HtmlEncode(GetAppRootUrl(false)) %>/images/edlogo.gif" alt="logo"/>
```

Comment: is it applies to `a href=""`? I think `<a runat="server" ... />` not same that `<a  ... />` . ***not same behaviour*** for `runat=server` than not

Comment: Maybe `src="<%= Page.ResolveUrl("~/images/edlogo.gif") %>"` ?

Answer (score 1):

there is something missing from your post, can you post it please?

You could use relative pathing

```
 <img src="../images/edlogo.gif" alt="logo"/>
```

Your code sample will always get it from the root directory.

Answer (score 1):

Use relative urls. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178116.aspx) e.g. "images/bg.jpg" in the page "http://v2/default.html" will point to "http://v2/images/bg.jpg" while the same code in the page "http://v2/v3/default.html" will point to "http://v2/v3/images/bg.jpg"

So your code becomes :

`img src="images\edlogo.gif" alt="logo"/>`

However, an unfortunate side effect is that you can't move your homepage around in your website directory structure without breaking the link.

I'm curious however why you would choose this sort of setup ? Wouldn't it be easier to just make a v3 a website and place it on the same directory level as v2 ?

Comment: I'm curious however why you would choose this sort of setup ? Wouldn't it be easier to just make a v3 a website and place it on the same directory level as v2 ?
doing so i Cannot have multiple web.config and same name dll's in the bin folder

Comment: i have already developed whole website using the \ links because i was thinking to deploy it directly as a website, but now i have to deploy it in a virtual directory so what can i do now?

Comment: Well, if you really have to deploy it in a virtual directory, you could use [URL rewriting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972974.aspx#urlrewriting_topic5). Place a web.config file in the V3 project with rewrite rules so that the urls point to the files in the V3 project instead of the V2 project. It is however a hack because all your urls are still wrong. You only redirect them to the correct file on the moment they browser uses the urls. Is a global find-and-replace (maybe with some regex) not an option ?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use  `HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppVirtualPath`  or  `Request.ApplicationPath`.

Too `Page.ResolveUrl("~")` is useful.

> Usage sample for my virtual directory **/v2**

```
    HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppVirtualPath = /v2
    Request.ApplicationPath = /v2
    Request.FilePath = /v2/Inicio.aspx
    GetAppRootUrl(false) = http://localhost:2029/v2
    Page.ResolveUrl("~") = /v2/
```

Answer (score 0):

Review **System.Web.VirtualPathUtility** Class & Methods (.Net 2.0 and Later)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.virtualpathutility.aspx

Review **System.Web.HttpRequest** Object

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.filepath(v=vs.100).aspx

```
Public Function GetRoot() As String
    Return System.Web.VirtualPathUtility.MakeRelative(Request.FilePath, Request.ApplicationPath)
End Function
```